# Difference between "Add me" and "Add me up"?

Tags: american-english, slang, colloquial-language

I want people to add me on the social app Snapchat. What should I write in the caption? Should I give my username on Facebook and say "Add me up"?

What's the difference between "Add me" and "Add me up" and which one is the correct one?

Comment: I don't have a strong enough opinion to write a full answer, but "Add me up" sounds like a slang way of saying "Add me", which sounds less demanding and less formal. I think the reason it sounds like that to me is because it sounds like "Hit me up", which is an informal way of telling people to contact you. However, it does sound a little strange and is definitely not very common, so I'm not sure I would recommend it

Answer (score 4):

I would say "Please add me as a Snapchat friend." Another option that is very slightly awkward might be "Could you add me as a Snapchat friend?". "Could you" is maybe a little more formal which is a tiny bit odd in this context. 
"Add me up" would be used more like a situation where you are closing out a bar tab at a bar and you ask the bartender to "Add me up" meaning "add up my bill so I can pay."

Comment: This is when in talking to someone, but when i text or write on other social websites, Facebook, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

*Add up* is a phrasal verb meaning "to total a list of numbers", or "to make sense."  It's different in meaning from plain *add*.

*Add me up* mistakenly implies you are list of numbers.  So just say *add me*.